# How to unset partition letter?

Tags: powershell

I have an external drive with ext4 filesystem. I would like to assign disk letter to disk drive. I can do that using powershell command:
`Get-Partition -DiskNumber 3 | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter X`.
Now I would like to unset this X's drive letter. How can I do that? I prefer powershell command solution.

Comment: There's a cmdlet, [Remove-PartitionAccessPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/remove-partitionaccesspath?view=windowsserver2022-ps) for that.

Comment: @vonPryz Thank you for answer. When I tried: ```Remove-PartitionAccessPath -DriveLetter X``` I get error ```Remove-PartitionAccessPath : No MSFT_Partition objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to 'X'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.```

Comment: @vonPryz I don't see that X letter, when I run ```Get-volume```. Only when I run ```Get-partition```

Comment: @vonPryz Maybe because I run ```Remove-PartitionAccessPath -DriveLetter X``` as Admin and ```Get-Partition -DiskNumber 3 | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter X``` as no admin